# GitHub Repo working but Heroku still the same

Tags: heroku, github, ruby-on-rails-4

When i'm pushing to github, the push works fine **and my Repo is properly updated**.

When deploying to Heroku, although it shows that everything works, and it pulled from the master (as i understand) the Files don't get updated.

```
76180b5..7bd1ec4  master -> master
```

I'm trying to get this working for hours now.. I even deleted the whole folder from my computer.. Set everything from scratch up.. But still not updating on Heroku...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, everyone has his stupid moments...

actually not precompiling my assets was the problem.

```
rake assets:clean
rake assets:precompile
```

and everything works again..

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try removing your heroku repo from your local machine, and adding again?

```
git remote rm heroku
$ heroku git:remote -a newname
```

Comment: No :( i even deleted my local files re downloaded it. Set everything up and deployed again.. But still the same ...

Comment: This is strange - we can go into a chat if you want to show me the problems?